# Make a total in an haskell (main)

Tags: haskell, increment

Basically, I have a loop that checks how many 'e' a user entered in one line. The thing is, I want it to show the total of e's entered total after every lines. Let's say he enters one line with 1 'e' in it the result will be 1, then after he enters the 2nd line that has 2 'e' in it, the total would be 3… and so on until the line is empty.

Here is my code so far. The problem with it: I don't know how to make a "total". I'm not sure if I'm clear... The current code will give the amount of 'e' found in each lines but not the total.

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter your line"
  line <- getLine
  if line == ""
     then return ()
  else do
      let v = nume line
      main
      print v

nume [] = 0
nume (x:xs)
 |x == 'e' = 1 + nume xs
 | otherwise = nume xs
```

Result:

```
Enter your line
there is 3 e
Enter your line
there are 4 e
Enter your line
only 1 e
Enter your line

1 <<-- Should be 8 (3+4+1)
4 <<-- Should be 7 (4+3)
3 <<-- ok
```

Comment: This can be simplified by the way if you write `unless (null line) $ do ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow you need to add the accumulation. The simplest change would probably be to factor out the recursive action and parameterize over the total, which is initially 0. Something like this:

```
inner n = do
  putStrLn "Enter your line"
  line <- getLine
  if line == ""
     then return ()
  else do
      let v = n + nume line
      inner v
      print v

main = inner 0

nume [] = 0
nume (x:xs)
 |x == 'e' = 1 + nume xs
 | otherwise = nume xs
```